# How to upgrade symfony from 1.4 to 2.1?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-1.4, symfony-2.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Porting a website from Symfony 1.4 to 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700648/porting-a-website-from-symfony-1-4-to-2-0)

Can anybody tell me how and what approch I should take to upgrade symfony 1.4 to 2.1?

Also let me know if this is not possible.

I have not done upgradation process before this, so it will be helpful if you provide me the points that I must consider.

Comment: Have you checked the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/symfony1/info) useful links ? There few interesting question about that: [Porting a website from Symfony 1.4 to 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700648/porting-a-website-from-symfony-1-4-to-2-0), [Effort required to go from Symfony 1.4 to Symfony 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157252/effort-required-to-go-from-symfony-1-4-to-symfony-2-0), [combine symfony1 and Symfony2 projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426627/combine-symfony1-and-symfony2-projects)

Comment: Asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5858095/422353 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/8157252/422353

Comment: @madth3 Thanks for the help. I guess I have to improve my skill on searching older questions.

Comment: May be useful: http://michelsalib.com/2011/07/10/a-symfony1-4-to-symfony2-migration-why-you-should-learn-symfony2/